# Removing "SUB" characters (ASCII=26, which is outside of normally searchable special characters) with powershell

Tags: powershell, text

I'm trying to remove all of the SUB (substitute, ASCII=26) characters from a large text file

I want to import a large file into sas, but sas bombs out (actually it just stops and reports a success, which is much worse) when it reaches an ususual character that looks like a "->" when viewed in excel.  Using the Code() function in excel, it identifies this character as a "26" which I believe is the ASCII 26 or SUB (substitute) character.

Anyway, I'd like to remove all these "->" characters from the file so I can import them into sas, so was thinking I could use powershell (one of the few tools available to me).

I'm new to powershell, but none of the documentation I've been able to find on `Select-String` has information on writing hex or arbitiray ascii characters, just a fixed list of normal special characters that doesn't include the character I'm struggling with.

Any ideas how I can remove all the SUB characters from a text file using powershell?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use \xnn in a regex to match arbitrary character codes expressed as hex.  026 = x1a

For Unicode, the format is \unnnn

```
Clear-Content $outputfile

Get-Content $inputfile -ReadCount 1000 |
 foreach { 
   $_ -replace '\u001a' |
   Add-Content $outputfile
  }
```

Comment: I'm testing this out, but the test is going about 20x slower than my get-content|select -skip 20302|set-content version I have which is just removing the one problem line that I've found so far, though I'm worried there may be other problem lines and will also have to manually add the problem line back in later after I clean it.  With my 20,000,000 row file, your code is going to take several days to run though, so that is a bit of a show-stopper. Is there a reason it is so much slower?

Comment: I didn't use the Encoding or ReadCount options when I ran it.  The final file was a 1-byte per character format, versus the original was a 2-byte per character format, so I think that means the input file isn't ASCII.  So I guess it could be the re-encoding work that slows it down so much? The skip version leaves the file still in a 2-byte per character format.

Comment: Then you need to match Unicode.  I'll update the answer for Unicode.  Leaving that ReadCount parameter off is what's making it slow.

Comment: Awesome, yes, that is working much faster.  I foolishly removed that thinking it was a rowcount for testing purposes.  Thanks for all the help.